# Increase connection attempt with DBI

Tags: r, shiny, dbi

I'm trying to build a Shiny application which will be connected to an unstable PostgreSQL Database with DBI. It works fine when the database is stable, but gives Whitelabel Error whenever the database is slow or down for a moment. How can I configure my application so that it will keep trying to connect a number of times before throwing error? A sample code is given below:

```
library(shiny)
library(DBI)

con <- dbConnect(
  RPostgres::Postgres(),
  host = "myip",
  port = "myport",
  dbname = "mydb",
  user = "user",
  password = "password"
)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tableOutput("mytable")
)

server <- function(input, output, session){
  output$mytable <- renderTable(
    dbGetQuery(
      con,
      "select * from mytable;"
    )
  )
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Have a look at `?tryCatch`

Comment: should I use tryCatch with dbConnect only, or every dbGetQuery?

Comment: I think the answer to your question is: ***both***, and using separate recovery logic. That is, if `dbConnect` fails, then I'll infer that most of your app is no longer able to do its job. If a specific query fails, it will likely be due to (1) you changing the query and not sufficiently testing it; or (2) the user entered inappropriate inputs (i.e., in a form field) and you should probably do some error-cleaning before attempting `dbGetQuery`. (Both of these reasons are due to insufficient testing of the app.) Possibly (3) the database is having other failures, outside of your control.

Answer (score 1):

We can try `purrr::insistently()` with `rate_backoff` as suggested by @r2evans, to retry the query waiting longer between each time up to a maximum of 4 in this case.

```
library(shiny)
library(DBI)
library(purrr)

con <- dbConnect(
  RPostgres::Postgres(),
  host = "myip",
  port = "myport",
  dbname = "mydb",
  user = "user",
  password = "password"
)

my_rate <- rate_backoff(
  pause_base = 1,
  pause_cap = 60,
  pause_min = 1,
  max_times = 4,
  jitter = FALSE
)


ui <- fluidPage(
  tableOutput("mytable")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$mytable <- renderTable(
    insistently(~
    dbGetQuery(
      con,
      "select * from mytable;"
    ), rate = my_rate, quiet = FALSE)()
  )
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: ***Strongly*** encourage the use of `max_times` (and perhaps `rate_backoff` instead of `rate_delay`), otherwise this app becomes a liability every time (1) the query is changed, (2) the database is in some maintenance mode, (3) the database is already failing for another reason, and now this becomes more problem to pile on top, *every second*.

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer. I can't upvote yet, but I'll do that once I get enough reputation to do that.